# Consulta Eloquent select total

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando agrupar para trazer totais na minha consulta que está no mysql

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as total
       ,e.descricao
  FROM pedido_cliente p
  INNER JOIN estabelecimentos e on e.id = p.estabelecimento_id
  GROUP BY p.estabelecimento_id,descricao
```

Que traz o seguinte resultado

```
total  |  descricao
   1   |   spermercado
   20  |   mercadinho
   10  |   loja
```

No formato eloquent

```
$totais = Pedido_cliente::with('estabelecimento')
                        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total' ,'estabelecimento'),
                        ->groupBy('estabelecimento_id')
                        ->get()
```

Onde `estabelecimento_id` é a chave estrangeira da coluna `id` da tabela `estabelecimentos`

Porém a coluna descrição vem **vazia**

tabela **estabelecimento**

```
id   | descricao 
 1   | Supermercado
 2   | Mercadinho
 3   | Loja
```

**pedido cliente**

```
id   | estabelecimento_id | pedido
 1   |     1              | 5
 2   |     3              | 4
 3   |     2              | 3
```

Model **Pedido_cliente**

```
class Pedido_cliente extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'pedido_cliente';        

    public function estabelecimento() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Estabelecimento', 'estabelecimento_id');
    }
}
```

Modelo **estabelecimento**

```
class Estabelecimento extends Model
{
}
```

Por que a descrição vem nula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só colocar `estabelecimento_id` na sua `SQL` e pela relação de carga adiantada pegar a `descricao` da tabela `estabelecimento`, exemplo:

```
$totais = Pedido_cliente::with('estabelecimento')
                        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total','estabelecimento_id'),
                        ->groupBy('estabelecimento_id')
                        ->get()


foreach($totais as $t)
{ 
    $total = $t->total;
    $descricao = $t->estabelecimento->descricao;
}
```

Nesse caso em especifico isso já é o suficiente.